# phonetype returns GSM although i am attached to a CDMA cell?

Tags: android, 3g-network

I have 2 questions concerning network information:

1) when i try to see the phone type :

```
int phoneType = phoneManager.getPhoneType();
```

I always have `PHONE_TYPE_GSM`, and when I see the network `Type( getNetworkType())` I get `Type_HSDPA`, is it normal?

2) I tried to get the PSC of the cell i always also have -1 even though an HSDPA cell should also have a PSC like the CDMA cell is there a way to have 3G  and 3G+ information about a cell ?

I am using android API 10 (2.3.3)

Thanks a lot for your helps guys

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on this information. Vendors set this value, but custom ROMs can change it.

Comment: um ok thanks and for the second question do you have an idea ? thanks for your help